Fish unknown option ---is-valid error evertime I enter a command
A ss from my terminal, everytime i execute a command it is showing the following error in my terminal , any fix would be entertained.

Please include your Ubuntu and fish version - the latter is particularly relevant, see also Fish shell error command line

What is your prompt? type fish_prompt
